# Blank Icon when using Material Icons in PrimeNg MenuBar

Tags: angular, angular-material, icons, primeng, menuitem

We are using Angular 12. As material library have more wide range of icon, we are interested in using that icon in PrimeNg MenuBar

```
<p-menubar [model]="menu"></p-menubar>
```

But, those material icons are not appearing on the screen. It's just blank without an icon.

```
this.menu = [{
      label: 'Products',
      icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user-edit',
      items: [{
              label: 'New / Update', icon: 'how_to_reg', routerLink: ['/products']
          },
          {
            label: 'Review', icon: 'task', routerLink: ['/review']
          }]
    }];
```

Any suggestions?

**Solution Tried**:

- Added prefix "ui-icon-"
- Used just icon name

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about `icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user-edit',`

But to use Angular material icons:

- Install Angular Material in project via `ng add @angular/material`
- Import `MatIconModule` in module.ts using
  `import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';`
- In your `menubar` component, you can have something like:

`<mat-icon>{{menu.icon}}</mat-icon>`

> Sample and API of [Mat Icon Module](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview)

- and in the parent component:

```
this.menu = [{
      label: 'Products',
      icon: 'person',
      items: [{
              label: 'New / Update', icon: 'how_to_reg', routerLink: ['/products']
          },
          {
            label: 'Review', icon: 'task', routerLink: ['/review']
          }]
    }];
```

> Here `person` is the value for icon and it can be found here: [Angular Material Icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material+Icons)I

Comment: Material Icon is already used in project. Only problem here is, menubar component is not having any option to customize template. More details : https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/menubar

Comment: @VaibhavSawant Have you imported MenubarModule in your module.ts file?
`import { MenubarModule } from 'primeng/menubar';`

Comment: Also, try initializing your local `menu` variable with MenuItem class.  
`private items: MenuItem[];`  
`import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/api';`

Comment: Where you are suppose to add below line <mat-icon>{{menu.icon}}</mat-icon>
in below piece of code?

<p-menubar [model]="items">
    <ng-template pTemplate="start">
        <img src="assets/showcase/images/primeng.svg" height="40" class="mr-2">
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="end">
        <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Search">
    </ng-template>
</p-menubar>

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for using material icons in primeng but it need to use some css to properly set the image and icon.

```
this.menuItems = [
  {
    label: '<p>Home <span class="material-symbols-outlined">home</span></p>',
    escape: false
  }
];
```

how its look in ui

[image]

make sure to use `escape: false` in your menuitem.